# Json object array

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

```
.ajax({
  cache: false,
    url: '/Dashboard/ListofNames',
    data: {
        charSearch: txtboxvalue
    },
    success: function (res){
        var obj = JSON.parse(res); //this object contains 1 index which is 0. 
        var parseObj = JSON.parse(obj[0].JsonResult) // This line is working i successfully gets the data from index 0
        var parseObj2 = JSON.parse(obj[1].JsonResult) //This is not working because index 1 is not existing, what i want is instead of getting an undefined exception, i want to set the index 1 into an empty string or whatever solution that i wont get any undefined exception.

    }
});
```

Any suggestion would really help me thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Considering your JSON.parse of object given the response as this object.
let res = [
    { name: "john", id: 1, JsonResult: "json-stringified-object-or-string" }
]
JSON.parse(res[0] ? res[0].JsonResult : '""');
JSON.parse(res[1] ? res[1].JsonResult : '""');
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution. I checked all of the undefined obj and set a new value for each. I created a loop to check every undefined obj after that i created a new object with Empty string and push it inside my jsonresult. Not a good practice, but it does the job.